# This a working code from a course I have enrolled, Can you help me understand the part where I have added a comment against the line in script?

Tags: python-3.x, python-class, python-object

```
def get_event_date(event):
  return event.date

def current_users(events):
  events.sort(key=get_event_date)
  machines = {}
  for event in events:
    if event.machine not in machines:
      machines[event.machine] = set()
    if event.type == "login":
      machines[event.machine].add(event.user)
    elif event.type == "logout" and event.user in machines[event.machine]:
        machines[event.machine].remove(event.user)
  return machines

class Event:
  def __init__(self, event_date, event_type, machine_name, user):
    self.date = event_date
    self.type = event_type
    self.machine = machine_name
    self.user = user

events = [
    Event('2020-01-21 12:45:56', 'login', 'myworkstation.local', 'jordan'),
    Event('2020-01-22 15:53:42', 'logout', 'webserver.local', 'jordan'),
    Event('2020-01-21 18:53:21', 'login', 'webserver.local', 'lane'),
    Event('2020-01-22 10:25:34', 'logout', 'myworkstation.local', 'jordan'),
    Event('2020-01-21 08:20:01', 'login', 'webserver.local', 'jordan'),
    Event('2020-01-23 11:24:35', 'logout', 'mailserver.local', 'chris'),
]
```

Please Help me understand the part, I don't get why is .event and . machine is used

1. #Doubt 1: event.date
2. #Doubt 2: event.machine

Comment: `event.date` accesses an attribute named `date` belonging to the object referenced by `event`. So in plain language, it gets the event's date. I suggest reviewing your course materials some more, because understanding of what objects and attributes are is very important.

Comment: @kaya3 I have added the entire code, could you help me better? Thank you!

Comment: It seems that there isn't any comment in your code anymore. It is hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.